# SwiftData is not working with Measurement<UnitType>

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

Trying to use Measurement in my SwiftData model and Xcode builds but simulator crashes with a fatal error. Testing on Xcode 15 beta 8. Xcode 15 RC release notes do not indicate any fixes or current issues, so is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpected type for CompositeAttribute: NSUnitLength

Debug console:

> SwiftData/SchemaProperty.swift:369: Fatal error: Unexpected type for
> CompositeAttribute: NSUnitLength

Item.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    var length: Measurement<UnitLength>
    
    init(length: Measurement<UnitLength>) {
        self.length = length
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue on apple developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732029

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with Xcode 15 SwiftData does not support Measurement<...> as persisted property.

As a suggested work around in the corresponding thread at the apple developer forum you could make your property @Transient and store the "reference value" in a Double as the example from @ebhamilton shows

```
var widthMaxMeters: Double? = nil
@Transient var widthMax: Measurement<UnitLength>? {
        get {
            if let widthMaxMeters {
                return Measurement<UnitLength>(value: widthMaxMeters, unit: .meters)
            } else { return nil }
        }
        set { widthMaxMeters = newValue?.value}
}
```

Above code enables you to access elegantly the Measurement property in SwiftUI while still have it persisted in SwiftData