SwiftData enum No exact matches in call to instance method 'setValue' error
I'm getting an "No exact matches in call to instance method 'setValue'" error for a property that has a enum as a value. How do I fix this? Any help would be appericated.

enum FluidUnit: CaseIterable, Identifiable {
  case ounce, liter
  var id: Self { self }

  var title: String {
    switch self {
    case .ounce:
      return "ounce"
    case .liter:
      return "liters"
    }
  }
}

@Model
class Drink: Identifiable, Hashable {

  let id: UUID = UUID()
  let name: String = ""
  var shortName: String = ""
  var amount: Double = 0.0
  let unitOfMeasure: FluidUnit = FluidUnit.ounce
  let date: Date = Date()
  var image: String = "water"
  var favorite: Bool = false

  init(name: String, amount: Double, unitOfMeasure: FluidUnit, image: String, favorite: Bool = false, shortName: String = "") {
    self.id = UUID()
    self.name = name
    self.amount = amount
    self.unitOfMeasure = unitOfMeasure
    self.date = Date()
    self.image = image
    self.favorite = favorite
    self.shortName = shortName
  }

  static func == (lhs: Drink, rhs: Drink) -> Bool {
    lhs.id == rhs.id
  }

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
      hasher.combine(id)
  }
}


Unrelated but Measurement is a much better tool for something like this

Unrelated 2 but do you really need your own implementation of the Hashable methods? Also the Model macro already makes your class conform to Hashable and Identifiable so no need to do it again. Read the documentation, it’s quite useful

@JoakimDanielson I added Hashable and Identifiable when I was building the class days before I added SwiftData. They would have been removed but this error happened, so I hadn't got around to removing them.

@loremipsum FYI Measurement doesn't work with SwiftData. Crashed my app on launch. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77243681/710793

I use it all the time you just have to use a computed property. BTW a transient computed property is overkill computed properties don’t get persisted anyways

I figured it out. I needed FluidUnit to conform to Codable. I also need to clean the build folder and the error went away.
